# Electron application built with electron-builder can't load image when installed in Program Files (x86)

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I've got an electron application that I've packaged using electron-builder. When I create a 64-bit installer and the application is installed to the 'Program Files' folder, I can load a background image for a div just fine from the 'Program Files\path\to\app\assets\images' folder.

However, if I package the application for 32-bit machine and it gets installed to the 'Program Files (x86)' path, the exact same image in the new location 'Program Files (x86)\path\to\app\assets\images' will not load.

There is no error thrown and everything else works fine. The image is set as a background style of a div using url('path\to\file'). When packaging for 32-bit there are ZERO code changes, I simply change the package.json's 'build' property for electron-builder to only package the 32-bit version.

I'm running it on a 64-bit machine right now and do not have an actual 32-bit machine to test on. If I take the installed 32-bit application and simply copy the files to the 'Program Files' folder, then it magically works again so it seems it has to do with the folder location specifically being in the x86 version of 'Program Files'.

For the life of me I am unsure where to start to debug something like this and why it might be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by writing and reading the data to the %APPDATA% folder. I know that is really the best way to do it anyway, but our previous app written in AIR worked fine writing to the Program Files folder and the 64-bit version of this app worked, I just couldn't figure out why the 32-bit version didn't. But it' snot important to have it there anyway.